# ADODB 5.21.0 Error with Reportico 6.03 module in Laravel 6 and PHP 7.4.24

Tags: php, laravel, adodb, reportico

I added the Reportico module following the instructions [here](http://www.reportico.org/laravel/public/index.php/installation)
I installed Reportico 6.0.3. Installation was successful. On launching Reportico and logging into design mode I get the error as shown in the image[Reportico error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grziy.png)
Help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with ADODB 5.21.0 and PHP 7.4 as described [here](https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/issues/733). I downgraded my ADODB to ver 5.20.20 and my issue was resolved. Hopefully, this will help someone else in the forum.